# if url not exist htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, indexing, query-string

I'm newbie in htaccess..

I have some conditions like this..

if user access

```
first/second/third
```

it's equal to

```
first.api.php?rquest=second&attr=third
```

but if the value of rquest is 'index', it will be erased from URL, like

```
first/third
```

equal to

```
first.api.php?rquest=index&attr=third
```

not

```
first/index/third
```

I had all night looking for solution, but no result.
I know system being confused if the request is index but attr has a value, it will treat the attr like rquest. see above, first/third, system will treat the 'third' segment as rquest.

Is it possible to rewrite url like that?

this is my work all night, I know this is still crap..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rquest=index
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ $1.api.php?rquest=$2&attr=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ $1.api.php?rquest=$2 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} rquest=index
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1.api.php?rquest=index&attr=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1.api.php?rquest=index [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /$1.api.php?rquest=$2&attr=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /$1.api.php?rquest=index&attr=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Not clear what you were trying to achieve with your old rewrite rules, but the above should do what you've described.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for fast response.. I've tried it, rquest 'index' with attr now is fixed. But another rquest so it doesn't work.
I think system skip rquest=$2 and prefers to read rquest 'index'